# 24 VAC signal rectifier and detection

Tags: signal, opto-isolator, rectifier

One of my projects consists of recovering a 24 VAC signal to give a run command.

To avoid using a relay with a 24 VAC coil I would prefer to convert the 24 VAC signal into a DC signal and use an optocoupler.

In the schematic below, I get the 24 VAC signal on connector J2, then the signal passes through a diode bridge (MB6S-E3/80), with a capacitance of 470 µF/35 V between + and ground at the output of the rectifier bridge.

Normally I should have a DC signal of 34 V (24 V x √2), with a 2 kΩ resistor, which should give about 16 mA on the optocoupler.

[image: 24Vac rectifier line]

Does this sound good and functional? Am I missing something?

Comment: Looks functional. You may want to consider putting a small resistor, say 50Ω or so, immediately after pin 1 of U3 to limit the in-rush current to the 470uF capacitor. You might want to add a very large bleeding resistor across C4 so that it can discharge when the power is removed. Not sure about your detailed requirement, but note that this will also generate valid signal if the voltage is lower, say 10Vac.

Comment: With 470µF it will be very slow to turn off. 35V is too low for the cap. If what comes after this can work with a pulsed input, it would be simpler to just use a rectifier, resistor, and no cap.

Answer (score 2):

> *Am I missing something?*

The [LTV824 opto-coupler](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/239/LTV-8X4_series_RevK-1710878.pdf) can take an AC current so you could just use a series resistor feeding it and not bother with the bridge rectifier.

[image]

On the output of the coupler you will need to add a capacitor to smooth the output. I expect you will have a resistor from the coupler's emitter to 0 volts and, that resistor may be around 10 kΩ so, add a capacitor of about 1 μF across it.

This will produce an RC time delay of about 10 ms and will probably be enough to derive a continuous logic level voltage for your monitoring circuitry. It should also be short enough so that when you lose the 24 volt AC supply, this is detected in less than 100 ms.

Comment: Hello Andy aka,

Thanks for your answer.
Indeed the LTV824 is AC/DC functional, I'll take note and make a version with an RC filter.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of potential issues with this scheme, and significant options to simplify it:

1. The 470uF capacitor is vastly oversized, and will continue supplying the ~>1mA current required to operate the optocoupler for *several seconds* after the 24V supply is lost. It's also big and expensive. Consider replacing it with at most 10uF, which results in a swing between 10 and 15mA throughout a 50Hz cycle - smaller at 60Hz ([simulation](https://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l5YCcyWrQDitA7NyBmAFn2wFYA2dAJjFJMRFMkZEM1IFMBaMMAKABuIRORD58oka0zMITMYShKYpPgHcQVKorabt4MFSh8AJnsW8jVdJjDZR+ECY4AzAIYBXADYAXU+c1CZmtbezEnV09ffzByWTCtC0Nw53dvPzNY+NFEwOZHVKi-DVztYP1xUUh1AMrhBwljDSzwMJaqbCNqkptWhtE7Kpr2zrFGjq6+AGMxgbC6ic0seDg0NbRNdGhqTrJYjtpEOmWEGrrB1li+ptnNUcIrxeqAJ0u50Qec-WD4PgAPVjyKiQbDSYJgZgWUReAD2bhMfH2bwCnzuVgiaV8XC8HEyymW-AAzvVpCiZEp3F5CRw+DClOSgohMEETqt7BQqKQlF0xLTwIoGZBkKxmDBIJzwEswIp8HwgA)). 35V is also a very tight specification for a capacitor that you're expecting to see run at 34V peak, especially given 24VAC supplies often have poor regulation. I would be sizing for 30VAC, 42VDC, so at least a 50V cap.
2. There is no protection against inrush. It will be better with a smaller capacitor, but you should consider a small (few tens to a hundred ohms) series resistor on either the AC or DC side of the rectifier.
3. There is little protection against overvoltage or mis-connection. You will need to decide whether it is worth the expense to harden this against inadvertent connection to e.g. 120/240V. It's probably reasonably resilient against static shock.

And finally, the answer @Andy aka beat me to:

- The optocoupler you're using can be directly fed AC, with only a current limiting resistor. This will result in a 'bouncy' output signal, but that be handled with a very small RC filter, depending on what is connected to the receiver. This presents a substantial parts savings of the capacitor and bridge rectifier, though a MOV or similar would probably be a good idea.

Comment: Hello SomeoneSomewhereSup,

Thank you for your very constructive reply, I have taken note and implemented the advice you gave me. 
Indeed, the LTV824 works in AC/DC, but I had this 'bouncy' effect in mind, I'll make a version with a small RC filter.